# Linux real time scheduling - kworker thread is unable to run and causing performance impact

Tags: linux, multithreading, linux-kernel, real-time, scheduling

I have an application were some threads are pinned to specific cores using CPU affinity.

I've tried to move those threads to real time priority policy with either SCHED_FIFO / SCHED_RR with the lowest priority available on the system in those policies:

```
param.sched_priority = sched_get_priority_min(SCHED_FIFO);
pthread_setschedparam(pthread_self(), SCHED_FIFO, &param);
```

As a result, I've suffered a high performance impact to those threads.

After some research I've discovered that the reason was that a thread called:
**kworker /1:0**
was in **R** state but was unable to run due to the fact that it had a regular policy and not real time and because of that starved.

When I moved this kworker thread to RT priority my application went back to exhibiting high performance:

```
chrt --fifo -p 99 <kworker_pid>
```

This seems like some kind of **priority inversion** where my thread is waiting for this kworker which has a lower priority and thus does not run.

I tried to figure out what exactly does this kwroker thread do and why having it stuck had such a high impact on my application, however, the only clue I got was from looking at it's kernel backtrace:

```
/proc/<kworker PID>/stack
[<ffffffff8107c1f3>] worker_thread+0x123/0x400
[<ffffffff810820be>] kthread+0xce/0xe0
[<ffffffff81602cec>] ret_from_fork+0x7c/0xb0
```

Any thoughts ?

Comment: The obvious one -- don't do stuff like this with a general purpose OS! It's almost impossible to avoid these kinds of problems. (What was that CPU doing? That's what you need to figure out. If your app wasn't making forward progress, why was it spinning the CPU? And if it was, what's your objection?)

Comment: @DavidSchwartz - noted...
but for the sake of curiosity...do you have any thoughts on what is going on ?

Comment: I don't think you'll be able to figure it out until you figure out what the CPU was doing. The problem was that whatever was running on that CPU was spinning it without making forward progress.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz - well, here is the tricky thing...my main thread wasn't stuck.
it was not spinning on a lock, waiting for a system call or anything like this.
it seems like it was doing some async call to the kernel and moved on...
and this async call had impact

Comment: Then why didn't the kworker thread run?

Comment: beacuse my main thread is not doing any sleep / IO - just computes and it has a RT priority and will not be preemted...at all.

Comment: Well, duh! Obviously that can't work. If there's anything else that CPU needs to do, how will it ever get done? If your code is willing to consume infinite CPU resources while getting 0 useful work done, you're sunk.

Comment: there are other cores available...but this kworker thread is pinned to the specific core and will not be migrated to another one.

Comment: Right. So, again, if there's anything else this CPU needs to do, how will it ever get done?

Comment: "while getting 0 useful work done" ???
how did you figure this out?
maybe it is trying to compute digits of PI ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133919/discussion-between-david-schwartz-and-itay-marom).

Comment: Linux is design to have soft RT threads, and it is designed to have threads that don't block or yield voluntarily -- but I don't think it's designed to have realtime threads that never block. If you really need realtime scheduling for a task that assumes 100% CPU then you need a different OS.

Answer (score 0):

To get an idea what the kworker thread is doing you can investigate the situation with `perf`.

Since a kworker thread usually executes workqueue-items you can look at a workqueue trace event, e.g.:

```
perf trace -e 'workqueue:workqueue_queue_work' --call-graph dwarf -C $CPU_NO
```

Where `$CPU_NO` is a CPU core number where a pinned thread of your application was blocked.

If the work-item was queued by an action that was executed an another CPU, you have to add a condition using bcc-trace or bpftrace, e.g. like this:

```
/usr/share/bcc/tools/trace -C -t -K -U \
    't:workqueue:workqueue_queue_work (args->req_cpu==1) \
    "%d => %d", args->cpu, args->req_cpu'
```

or

```
bpftrace -e ' tracepoint:workqueue:workqueue_queue_work /args->req_cpu==1/ \
{ printf("%d => %u   %s %s\n",  args->cpu, args->req_cpu, kstack, ustack)  }  '
```

(the tracepoint also has a string argument with the workqueue name which is also of interest here, but [might be tricky to access](https://github.com/iovisor/bpftrace/issues/385))

The stack-traces perhaps include enough hints to get an idea how your application triggered that workqueue item. And you get some pointers for researching whether you can do something about it - e.g. such that it doesn't happen on that CPU anymore ([see also Documentation/kernel-per-CPU-kthreads.txt](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/kernel-per-CPU-kthreads.txt) to get some initial tips).